# Error: Property 'innerHTML' does not exist on type 'Text'. angular 2+ . when print data table image not printed

Tags: angular, typescript, printing, angular-datatables

when i print angular data table by print.js 
An error comes ,

```
Property 'innerHTML' does not exist on type 'Text'.
```

What i do for print images in columns?

```
extend: 'print',
  exportOptions: {
    stripHtml: false,
    format: {
      body: function ( inner, coldex, rowdex ) {
        if (inner.length <= 0) {
          return inner;
        }
        const el = $.parseHTML(inner);
        let result = '';
        $.each( el, function (index, item) {
          if (item.nodeName === '#text') {
            result = result + item.textContent;
          } else if (item.nodeName === 'IMG') {
            result = result + item.outerHTML;
          } else if (item.nodeName === 'DIV') {
            result = result + item.innerHTML;
          } else if (item.nodeName === 'SUP') {
            result = result + item.outerHTML;
          } else if (item.nodeName === 'STRONG') {
            result = result + item.outerHTML;
          } else {
            result = result + item.innerText;
          }
        });
        return result;
      }
    }
  },
```

Print images with table.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution for this.
Add :---  const it =  item; and then replace item to it.
See below running code.

```
extend: 'print',
          exportOptions: {
            stripHtml: false,
            format: {
              body: function ( inner, coldex, rowdex ) {
                if (inner.length <= 0) {
                  return inner;
                }
                const el = $.parseHTML(inner);
                let result = '';
                $.each( el, function (index, item) {
                  **const it = <HTMLElement> item;**
                  if (item.nodeName === '#text') {
                    result = result + item.textContent;
                  } else if (item.nodeName === 'IMG') {
                    result = result + it.outerHTML;
                  } else if (item.nodeName === 'DIV') {
                    result = result + it.innerHTML;
                  } else if (item.nodeName === 'SUP') {
                    result = result + it.outerHTML;
                  } else if (item.nodeName === 'STRONG') {
                    result = result + it.outerHTML;
                  } else {
                    result = result + it.innerText;
                  }
                });
                return result;
              }
            }
          },
```